# Confused with how to implement view controller for cocoa app

Tags: objective-c, cocoa, serial-port, scenekit

I'm very new to objective-c and cocoa(started today), I have experience with java and this just seems like a different world. I'm building an app with scene kit and [OSRSerialPort](https://github.com/armadsen/ORSSerialPort)(Have looked at the example code and don't understand how the controller is connected to the view). The goal of this is to take accelerometer data from a micro controller and making a visual representation of it with scene kit. I've tried to implement my controller in the same way as the example project in OSRSerialPort's github. Mine just doesn't seem to work.  I'm just confused on why my project would don't receive input from the port but the example one receives it just fine when I feel as I've implemented it the correct way. I've attached the xCode project [here.](http://sharing.is.caring.s3.amazonaws.com/GroundStation)

Would love any help on this.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> I'm building an app with scene kit and OSRSerialPort(Have looked at
>   the example code and don't understand how the controller is connected
>   to the view)

With Xcode, you can connect a Controller to a View *without writing any code*.  When you use Xcode's Interface Builder(IB), almost non-readable xml data is inserted automatically into the .xib file for a window, which is the code that actually connects the two objects.

Then when your application starts, the .xib file is parsed, and the objects listed in the .xib file are created and the connections listed in the .xib file are setup.

I would guess that the connections you can't find are in the window's .xib file.

In fact, ORSSerialPort's README.md says this:

> This application demonstrates that it is possible to setup and use a
>   serial port with ORSSerialPort **without writing a lot of "glue" code**.
>   Nearly all of the UI is implemented using Cocoa bindings.

*without writing a lot of "glue" code* means that instead of writing code the developers did a lot of dragging between objects in IB.  And [Cocoa bindings](https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/documentation/Cocoa/Conceptual/CocoaBindings/CocoaBindings.html) is a term of art, but you'll see that you have to understand other things first.

After figuring out how to download the project and open it locally in Xcode, I was able to look at MainMenu.xib in IB. Below is a screen shot of what MainMenu.xib looks like in IB, and on the right hand side there is a partial list of the connections for ORSSerialPortDemoController:

[image]

Those connections were established without writing any code.

> I'm very new to objective-c and cocoa(started today)

Well, then put your current project aside, and learn the basics of how to use Xcode in Hello World style apps, then work your way up.  As you progress in your learning, you will know when you are ready to go back to your current project.